I am trying to GET http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve data from this API to my react app
I have tested the APIs in postman. And all the APis are working as it should be. The process is once i login using POST http://localhost:3001/login this will give me 'session': 'f3goquoujo6'in JSON format. And that 'session': 'f3goquoujo6' is passed into the header of GET http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve API so that the server responds with all the user data. All these works in postman. But i could not figure out to do it on my react app. My app looks like this
`
  import "./userList.css";

    import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
    import {DeleteOutline, Block} from '@mui/icons-material';
    // import { userRows, trainerRows } from "../../../dummyData";
     import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
     import { useState, useEffect } from "react";`




 `   export default function UserList() {
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);
     const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState('');
     // const [sessionID, setSessionID] = useState('');

      useEffect(() => {
      // Login as admin to get session ID
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              email: 'rohit@gmail.com',
              password: 'password123',
          }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          // Store the session ID in localStorage
          localStorage.setItem('sessionID', data.session);
          
          // Fetch initial user data
          // const url = selectedRole === 'All_User'
          //     ? 'http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve'
          //     : 'http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve';
          // Function to get the stored session ID
          const getSessionId = () => {
            return localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
          };
          const sessionId = getSessionId();
          const url = 'http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve';
          fetch(url, {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'session': `${sessionId}`,
              },
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
              // Ensure data is an array of objects
              if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                  setData(data);
              } else {
                  console.error('Received data is not an array:', data);
              }
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching users:', error));
            
     ` })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error logging in:', error));
  }, [selectedRole]);
  ``

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        setData(data.filter(item=>item.id!==id))
    }
    const handleRoleChange = (event) => {
      setSelectedRole(event.target.value);
    };
  
    
    
    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
        { field: 'first_name', headerName: 'First Name', width: 150,
            // renderCell: (params) => {
            //     return (
            //         <div className="userListUser">
            //             <img className="userListImage" src={params.row.profile_image} `                     `your text``alt="Profile" srcset="" />`
            //             {params.row.username}
            //         </div>
            //     )
            // }
        },
        { field: 'last_name', headerName: 'Last Name', width: 150 },
        {
          field: 'email',
          headerName: 'Email',
          width: 120,
        },
        {
          field: 'user_type',
          headerName: 'User Type',
          width: 150,

        },
        {
            field:'action',
            headerName:'Action',
            width:150,
            renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                    <div className="userListAction">
                        <Link to = {"/user/" + params.row.id}>
                            <button className="userListEdit">Edit</button>
                        </Link>
                        
                        <DeleteOutline className="userListDelete" onClick={() =>     `your text`handleDelete(params.row.id)}/>
                        <Block className="userListBlock"/>
                    </div>
                    
                )
            }
        },
      ];
     
    return (
   
  `  <div className="userList">
       <div className="userDropdown">
        <select className= "userDropdownicon" value={selectedRole} onChange={handleRoleChange}>
          <option value="All_User">All User</option>
          <option value="Trainer">Trainer</option>
          <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
        </select>
      </div>`
        <DataGrid
        rows={data}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 8 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
       )
    }

I tried to hit the GET http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve and the data was supposed to be on this table. But it does not show anything.`

You are setting the value to the local storage with key: "sessionID". But when you try to get the value from the local storage, you are referring the key: "sessionId". Looks like it is a typo error.
